# Combining AdWords Remarketing and RLSA tags

Tags: google-ads-api

I am impementing both AdWords Remarketing tag and the AdWords RLSA tag. Does anyone know if they can be combined?

AdWords Remarketing:

```
<script>
var google_tag_params = {
ecomm_prodid: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
ecomm_pagetype: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
ecomm_totalvalue: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE'
}
var google_conversion_id = 1002886111;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
</script>script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
```

AdWords Remarketing List for Sales Ads (RLSA) tag:

```
<script>
var google_conversion_id = 1002886111;
var google_conversion_label = "999_CKTrkgoQeKmb3gM";  
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
```

I am guessing yes based on the fact that I don't see Google mentioning that one must come before the other and that it uses global vars that will cascade down but wanted to double check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the first AdWords remarketing tag on its own - no need for the second RLSA tag.

This is because the first tag will generate an audience that can be used with RLSA on its own anyway.  If you add in the second tag it will create another separate audience in AdWords, but it will be identical to the other ones.

Comment: Well don't I need the label? The label came from me generating a 180 days rlsa tag for one of the campaigns. What if I had multiple labels? Are none of them needed?

Comment: The label identifies the second tag as something separate from the first tag (the first tag is your account's main remarketing list's tag).  When you create additional tags for your account, each one gets a unique label so that Google knows what list to put the users into.  If you are using two tags in the same place, you may as well just use one tag as you'll be generating identical lists otherwise which seems like a waste of time.